# ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests.get (import requests) to scrape some metrics by connecting to some HTTP endpoint.

I am able to run connect to the endpoints while running the command manually -

```
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> output = requests.get("http://10.206.124.139:9209/metrics/8ebab4dd-  84bd-48c2-998c-aade88d8c82c/46567dbe-24d0-4cca-b432-a28ac5e831ec/0e297dfe-c64d-4139-bb14-a884c3e1ebc9/dbd5ca46-de73-4fe0-8273-9a9a0f5faa7a/549b0b1a-d3cc-47f0-8917-3919cb432aa6")
>>> output.text   ---> I am able to see the output.
```

When I try to run the same command via my python script i get the below error-

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service   not known'))
```

Snippet of my Code -

```
target_end_point = target_end_point.replace("127.0.0.1:10090",    self.replace_string)
metrics = requests.get('http://%s' % target_end_point)
```

target_end_point looks like below when i print it -

```
final target endpoint is           "10.206.124.139:9209/metrics/8ebab4dd-84bd-48c2-998c-aade88d8c82c/46567dbe-24d0-4cca-b432-a28ac5e831ec/0e297dfe-c64d-4139-bb14-a884c3e1ebc9/dbd5ca46-de73-4fe0-8273-9a9a0f5faa7a/549b0b1a-d3cc-47f0-8917-3919cb432aa6"
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

When you insert string into function calls, python repr of the string isn't compatible wit the requests.get() call. This is what python feeds into the call (notice the extra quotes):

```
repr(target_endpoint) # -->"'127.0.0.1:10090/metrics/8ebab4dd-84bd-48c2-998c-aade88d8c82c/46567dbe-24d0-4cca-b432-a28ac5e831ec/0e297dfe-c64d-4139-bb14-a884c3e1ebc9/dbd5ca46-de73-4fe0-8273-9a9a0f5faa7a/549b0b1a-d3cc-47f0-8917-3919cb432aa6'"
```

Convert the string to bytes:

```
target_end_point = target_end_point.replace("127.0.0.1:10090",    self.replace_string)
target_end_point = target_end_point.encode() # encode the variable
metrics = requests.get(b'http://' + target_end_point) # change the 'http:// to a bytestring
```

And you should be good to go.